# How to access members of type std::vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

my program has a function to calculate some sum, for this i need to access attributes of objects in vector:

declaration of vector:

```
class trilateration {
public:
    ...
    std::vector<tip> *potential;
    ...
};
```

then in constructor its initialized:

```
trilateration::trilateration()
{
...
potential = new std::vector<tip>();
...
}
```

class tip looks like this:

```
class tip {
public:

double sum;
Point2d *pt;
tip();
tip(double x, double y);
virtual ~tip();
};
```

tip constructor:

```
tip::tip(double x, double y)
{
pt = new Point2d(x,y);
sum=0;
}
```

objects are added to vector in some function like this:

```
potential->push_back(tip1);
```

then i want to access some objects in vector like this:

```
void trilateration::get3points()
{

for(int i=0; i<potential->size(); ++i)
{
    for(int j=0; j<potential->size(); ++j)
    {
        potential[i].sum=potential[i].sum+normalize(potential[i].pt,potential[j].pt);
    }

}
}
```

while compilation im getting follwoing error:

```
error: ‘class std::vector<tip>’ has no member named ‘sum’
error: ‘class std::vector<tip>’ has no member named ‘pt’
```

how can i acess these attributes from vector?

**EDIT:**

after changing potential to be a member of trilateration and pt to be member of tip, program compiled but when it encounters

```
potential.push_back(tip1);
```

throws:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./loktest: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00792f10 ***
```

Comment: You need to dereference since `potential` is a pointer to `vector<tip>`: `(*potential)[i]`. You shouldn't have a pointer for that vector at all IMHO.

Comment: As a sidenote: If there is no good reason for `potential` to be a pointer don't force it to be one. Same goes for `pt` of `tip`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless there are *strong* reasons to have pointer data members and to allocate your objects on the heap using `new`, don't do that.

Your code seems to use a kind of Java-style, but this is **C++**, not Java. Enjoy the *automatic* resource management of C++, and the power of C++ destructors. Just define data members without using pointers and dynamic allocations.

In class `trilateration`, change from `vector<tip>*` to `vector<tip>`:

```
class trilateration {
public:
    ...
    // WAS std::vector<tip> *potential;
    std::vector<tip> potential;
    ...
};
```

In `trilateration`'s constructor, you don't need to create the vector dynamically; just delete the line allocating the vector with `new`:

```
trilateration::trilateration()
{
    ...
    // REMOVED:
    // potential = new std::vector<tip>();
    ...
}
```

Note that in your previous code, when you allocated the vector with `new`, you had to properly `delete` it in the destructor, and provide proper copy operations (copy constructor and copy assignment), or ban copies marking the aforementioned operations `=delete`.

Instead, you don't need all this complicated stuff if you have an ordinary simple non-pointer data member.

The same goes for your `tip` class.
Unless there is a strong reason to have a `Point2d*` data member, just use a `Point2d` (non-pointer) data member:

```
class tip {
public:

  double sum;

  // WAS: Point2d *pt;
  Point2d pt; // <-- note: no pointers here

  tip();
  tip(double x, double y);

  // NOTE: Do you really need a virtual destructor here?? 
  virtual ~tip();
};
```

Change the constructor as well:

```
tip::tip(double x, double y)
    : pt(x, y), sum(0)
{
  // REMOVE:
  // pt = new Point2d(x,y);
  //sum=0;
}
```

Your code gets simplified, and you'll avoid some bugs and headaches.

Comment: thanks, for code correction, i have fixed in my code what you pointed, my program has compiled but im still getting `glibc detected` when i try `potential.push_back(tip1);` any idea whats causing it?

Comment: @Cynizm if an answer is usefull, cinsider upvoting it. AS regard with your glibc corruption, please open a new question with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Since `trilateration::potential` is a `std::vector<tip>*`, `potential[i]` is a `std::vector<tip>` located at `trilateration::potential + i`. This is not what you want.

```
for(int j=0; j<potential->size(); ++j)
{
    (*potential)[i].sum=potential[i].sum+normalize((*potential)[i].pt,(*potential)[j].pt);
}
```

is a possible hack. But what you *really* want is to get rid of all those useless pointers. Make the vector a member variable of your class and stop using `new` where it is not needed.

Comment: making potential to be a member, and also pt a member caused  "*** glibc detected *** ./loktets: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00ff2de8 ***"

Comment: I can't help with the full code, but you have a lot to work with.

Comment: @Cynizm You probably have more useless pointers used in your code. Making `potential` a member shouldn't cause such error per se.

Comment: this error apeears when i try to do "potential.push_back(tip1);

Comment: @Cynizm: Your classes with those pointer data members have bogus copy semantics: you have shallow copies of pointers, instead of deep copies of values. I'm also not sure if you have destructors in which you release dynamically allocated resources. I also wrote an answer, with modifications to your tip class as well. You can avoid all this headache using a more proper C++ coding pattern (instead of pointers and dynamic allocations, when they are not needed).